# Drywall cracked while installing a TV wall mount

Tags: walls, cracks

We were drilling in the TV mount into a stud and the drywall cracked. Is it still safe to hang our TV? Or should I be concerned that the stud won’t hold the TV?

Comment: if it is a  2x4 stud it will hold the TV

Comment: you do not drill in the studs, maybe pre drill for the screw with small drill

Comment: If you're putting in lag bolts @Ruskes, you sure to drill pilot holes! A 1/4" or 3/8" lag bolt isn't going to go into a stud all on its own, and if you do manage to get it started, it's likely to wander out the side of the stud or blow the thing apart.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include pictures of the situation. Include a pic of the "cracked" drywall, as well as the size of the screw/bolt that you're using to attach the TV mount, and the drill bit you're using to drill the holes.

Comment: @FreeMan that is what I said so what is your point ? to be precise, choose a drill that is not more but slightly less the the bolt/screw inner diameter of the thread.  How do you know, hold the drill parallel to the screw.

Answer (score 2):

Drywall is just decoration.  Studs are structural.

If drywall cracks it just does not look nice.  If studs crack, you got problems.

It is odd that the drywall cracked when drilling.  Maybe expand your question to include when the drywall cracked.  Simple drilling should not crack drywall, tightening the mounting screws too much is possible to crack drywall by squeezing it too much.

Comment: more of a comment than answer